# gauge chart to be displayed on selection of Youtube video id

Tags: visualforce

Apex Class :

```
public class Speedometer 
{
public WrapperCounter wc{get; private set;}

private final String apiKey = 'AIzaSyAy641eNaFaV-SuQRP88YeZ75qbJfxUZhI';
public String selectedVideo{get;set;}

class WrapperCounter
{

    public Integer viewCount{get;set;}
    public Integer likeCount{get;set;}
    public Integer commentCount{get;set;}

    public WrapperCounter(Integer viewCount, Integer likeCount, Integer commentCount)
    {
        this.viewCount = viewCount;
        this.likeCount = likeCount;
        this.commentCount = commentCount;
    }
}

public List<SelectOption> getVideos()
{

    List<SelectOption> lstSO = new List<SelectOption>();
    lstSO.add(new SelectOption('None', '--None--'));
    lstSO.add(new SelectOption('VasWcH5vCTs', 'Djokovic'));
    lstSO.add(new SelectOption('jDn2bn7_YSM', 'AR Rehman'));
    lstSO.add(new SelectOption('wlWsIH_bUKU', 'Michael Jackson'));
    return lstSO;
}

public Speedometer()
{
    selectedVideo  = 'None';
    getYoutubeVideoCounter();
}

private void getYoutubeVideoCounter()
{
    if(selectedVideo == 'None') 
       return;
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();        
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id='+ selectedVideo + '&key='+apiKey);

    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);


    fromJSON f = fromJSON.parse(res.getBody());
    wc = new WrapperCounter(Integer.valueOf(f.items[0].statistics.viewCount), Integer.valueOf(f.items[0].statistics.likeCount), Integer.valueOf(f.items[0].statistics.commentCount));


}


   public void fetchYoutubeDataForSelectedVideo()
{
    system.debug('------------'+selectedVideo);
    getYoutubeVideoCounter();
}

}
```

VF Page :

```
<apex:page controller="Speedometer" sidebar="false">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["gauge"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ 
          ['Label', 'Value'],

          ['Likes', {!wc.likeCount}]


        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 560, height: 168,
          greenFrom: 60000, greenTo: 100000,
          redFrom: 0, redTo: 30000,
          yellowFrom: 30001, yellowTo: 60000,
          minorTicks: 5, max:100000
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);


      }
</script>
 <body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>
  </body>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Youtube Speedometer">

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Video" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVideo}" size="1" onchange="Speedo_GetStats();">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Videos}"/>
                </apex:selectList>

            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:actionFunction name="Speedo_GetStats" action="{!fetchYoutubeDataForSelectedVideo}" oncomplete="drawChart(parseInt({!wc.likeCount}));"/>
</apex:form>

<apex:outputPanel id="SP_Stats">
```

The gauge charge is not getting displayed on selection of value from selectlist . This is working fine for bar chart API . Is the above code fine or some changes required in javascript?
Scenario - number of LIKES for the selected video needs to be displayed.